# Add existing user pool to a lambda trigger in SAM

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

The documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-function-cognito.html

Says to reference User pool created in the same template. I can't believe that there's no way to reference existing user pool - is this right?

Is there any way to reference it in SAM as a lambda trigger if the user pool already exists?

Any time I try to reference existing user pool it throws an error.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem but no-found any solution in document.
When I created a UserPool in my template, It create a new pool ; but unable to reference an existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Oh Dear,

I'm facing the same problem and...

It seems to be impossible regarding this https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/develop/versions/2016-10-31.md#cognito

> NOTE: To specify a Cognito UserPool as an event source for a Lambda
> function, both resources have to be declared in the same template. AWS
> SAM does not support specifying an existing UserPool as an event
> source.

There is the same issue with S3 bucket: https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/issues/124#

Answer (score 0):

Although I am using serverless instead of SAM I managed to solve a similar issue by adding the 'existing' parameter like this:

```
functions:
postConfirmation:
handler: app/main/lambda_handler.handler
events:
  - cognitoUserPool:
      pool: MyUserPoolName
      existing: true
      trigger: PostConfirmation
```